# Anyway to prefill the function argument with other argument

Tags: python

I know that there are some similar topis on this, but I wonder that if there is a string argument that depend on other argument within a python function, is there an proper way of doing it(like the one below, but doesn't work)

```
def printMsg(defaultMsg=f"Hello {name}", name="John"):
    print(defaultMsg)
```

Comment: FWIW, you generally don't want this since it means arguments are either redundant or implicitly coupled (depending on how the function handles the relationship being broken). For example, in this case it would be better to have a message *template* into which the function actively inserts the name. Do you maybe have a concrete example of what you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

Or, if you want to be flexible specifying the message format

```py
def printMsg(msg_fmt='Hello {name}', **kwargs):
    print(msg_fmt.format(**kwargs))
```

and then

```
printMsg(name='John')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
def printMsg(name="John", defaultMsg=None):
    
    if defaultMsg is None:
        defaultMsg = f'Hello {name}'
    
    print(defaultMsg)
```